# Android - Failed to open database (SQLite)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am creating a database exporter library. I am taking whole database from supplied context

```
 mContext.databaseList() //return String[] of databases
```

And then taking each database using a loop

```
  File databasePath = mContext.getDatabasePath(databaseName);
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(databasePath.getAbsolutePath(), null, 0);
```

for testing purpose, I used a real-time project, then I noticed a database that i didn't create called

`SLM_B.db-journal.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back`

When I try to open this database I got this issue.

```
Failed to open database '/data/user/0/com.samsung.lighting/databases/SLM_B.db-journal.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back.back'.
                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: file is encrypted or is not a database (code 26): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
                  #################################################################
                  Error Code : 26 (SQLITE_NOTADB)
                  Caused By : File opened that is not a database file or encrypted.
                    (file is encrypted or is not a database (code 26): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode)
                  #################################################################
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1009)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:713)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:387)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:361)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:250)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:201)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:514)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:206)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:178)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:934)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:898)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:708)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:683)
                      at com.godwin.databasedebugger.DatabaseExporter.exportDB(DatabaseExporter.java:41)
                      at com.godwin.databasedebugger.TableListFragment.exportDatabase(TableListFragment.java:55)
                      at com.godwin.databasedebugger.TableListFragment.onViewCreated(TableListFragment.java:50)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1314)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:607)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1266)
                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6943)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3277)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:230)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1822)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
08-27 19:24:32.801 E: file is encrypted or is not a database (code 26): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
                  #################################################################
                  Error Code : 26 (SQLITE_NOTADB)
                  Caused By : File opened that is not a database file or encrypted.
                    (file is encrypted or is not a database (code 26): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode)
                  #################################################################
                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: file is encrypted or is not a database (code 26): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
                  #################################################################
                  Error Code : 26 (SQLITE_NOTADB)
                  Caused By : File opened that is not a database file or encrypted.
                    (file is encrypted or is not a database (code 26): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode)
                  #################################################################
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1009)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:713)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:387)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:361)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:250)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:201)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:514)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:206)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:178)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:934)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:898)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:708)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:683)
                      at com.godwin.databasedebugger.DatabaseExporter.exportDB(DatabaseExporter.java:41)
                      at com.godwin.databasedebugger.TableListFragment.exportDatabase(TableListFragment.java:55)
                      at com.godwin.databasedebugger.TableListFragment.onViewCreated(TableListFragment.java:50)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1314)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:607)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1266)
                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6943)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3277)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:230)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1822)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                    at com.andr
```

> And my questions are
>
> 1. why this database?
> 2. Is there anything like this for another type of application?
> 3. How to avoid this? (than String comparison)
> 4. How to encrypt or decrypt own database?

Comment: `databaseList()` returns all files in the databases private dir, including sqlite's internal journal files that are not databases per se. I assume it's your code that then keeps appending the `.back` suffixes to files in the same database private dir and then hits a wall at about 255 chars.

Comment: @laalto thanks for your reply. Why the `.back` present in database dir, and how can I filter only `.db` functions

Comment: How about checking something like `databasePath.endsWith(".db")`?

Comment: Now I did like that. But I didn't understand the purpose of journal there

Comment: @Godwin you may wish to read [Database File Format - 3. The Rollback Journal](https://sqlite.org/fileformat2.html)